# Data from two different DataTables in a DataSet does not show in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need to create a report base from two tables: patientinformation_tbl and daterecords_tbl
I have successfully retrieved the data that I needed from the two tables and added it in a dataSet.
When I build the program, the report created is blank.

Below is my code for creating my report:

```
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        DataTable info = _printResult.sample();
        DataTable date = _printResult.sample2();

        ds.Tables.Add(info);
        ds.Tables.Add(date);

        CrystalReport1 report = new CrystalReport1();
        report.SetDataSource(ds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

for my sample() code:

```
 public DataTable sample()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM patientinformation_tbl";
        DataTable _data = new DataTable("patientinformation_tbl");
        try
        {
            _connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(_data);
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex) { }
        _connection.Close();

        return _data;
    }
```

for sample2() code:

```
 public DataTable sample2()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM daterecords_tbl LIMIT 1";
        DataTable _data = new DataTable("daterecords_tbl");
        try
        {
            _connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(_data);
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex) { }
        _connection.Close();

        return _data;
    }
```

Comment: may you describe how the tables are linked inside crystal? may you describe which sessions are you using in crystal? is any of the tables empty?